# What is the simplest way to search a string for a substring matching a key in an associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I'm fairly new to PHP and I need a function that will check if a string input from the user contains a substring matching a key in an associative array.

So far I've been using the array_key_exists() function a lot to check if the input ~matches~ a key in an array, but I don't know how to go about doing this unless I search for each key one at a time. Maybe some kind of loop would be useful?

My code looks something like this:

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="off">
   <textarea id="wiyetxt" name="input"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
   <input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

```
$input = $_POST["input"];
$keywords = ["apple" => "Found 'apple'", "banana" => "Found 'banana'", 
  "carrot" => "Found 'carrot'"];
if ($input contains one of these keys) {
  echo(value which corresponds to the key);
}
else {
  echo("No keys were found");
}
```

Comment: oops my mistake, this isn't my real code though.

Comment: I didn't know what to try to be honest, as I said I'm new to the language. Just looking for some suggestions from the professionals :)

Comment: Please post the real code of your attempt. Also include a proper example of input data and what the expected result is. You should also include the result your current attempt gives you.

Comment: Warning** Pseudo code normally garners only Pseudo answers!!

Comment: You might like to [waste a few minutes of your life reading the PHP manual for the `in_array()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) :)

Comment: I'm okay with general suggestions, I probably shouldn't post my real code because it's a text-based game which is a personal project not meant to be seen by the Internet and I have a very dark sense of humour, wouldn't want to offend anyone.

Comment: @nomadofnowhere313  Start by doing a search like "PHP string exists in other string" to find out what function your should use for that part of the solution.  Then combine that with your idea of "Maybe some kind of loop would be useful".  You should be able to get most of the way there with some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `foreach` loop to search all the keywords, if the key value exists within $input, print the key's value.

```
 $keywords = ["apple" => "Found 'apple'", "banana" => "Found 'banana'",  "carrot" => "Found 'carrot'"];
  foreach ($keywords as $k => $v)
  {
     if (strstr($input, $k))
        print $v;

  }
```

Comment: Likely not terribly important for OP's use-case, but "If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead."

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you very much!